# Numpy load() memory overflow results in Segmentation fault

Tags: python, numpy

With the following code that leads to a memory overflow:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10000000)
np.save('a', a)

l = []
while True:
    l.append(np.load('a.npy'))
```

Python errors out a Segmentation fault, instead of a MemoryError. It seems to be the case for machines like AWS EC2 which don't have swap memory (I've tried with a machine with more RAM and a swap memory and I get a MemoryError).

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you multiple resources to go through below, but ***generally this is very much OS/system dependent***. [SegFlts](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aqsj)

**Simple answer:** You are probably getting it because you are **trying to access memory address which is not present in the memory**. **Its also possible to get *segFaults* when your memory module has issues** or because of any of the following(these should clear your doubts):

Look at : [Segfault instead of MemoryError when bytearray too big](https://bugs.python.org/issue22335)

Also, why segmentation fault? [Possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035541/what-causes-a-python-segmentation-fault)

Tracing a SegFault(If you still feel something is fishy!) : [python tracing a segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663841/python-tracing-a-segmentation-fault/2664232#2664232)

Refer: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127777/a-python-segmentation-fault)

The question asked is actually broad, as the answer to it may take pages of explanation(hence added relevant links).

Comment: It looks like the second link you provided reports a similar bug in Python3, and I verified that Python2 errors out a MemoryOverflow and not a Segfault. I'm not sure Numpy uses bytearray for its data container though. Anyways, that should be fixable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DavidBrochart Good to know it helped :)