# Calling 'python3' causes a segmentation fault

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, segmentation-fault

I have python3.7 installed in my RPi. When I call 'python3' as shown below I get the following error:

```
user@raspberrypi:~ /user_folder $ python3
Segmentation fault
```

When I run it using gdb I get the following error:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/python3

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x001100b0 in PyErr_SetObject ()
```

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling python3, but it did not work.
Also, python 2 works well without any issue.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Is `PYTHONSTARTUP` set?

Comment: Could be a package issue, have you tried ```sudo apt-get update/upgrade```?

Comment: You could get more answers for this in Suiperuser rather than in StackOverflow.

Comment: Try reinstalling all python related packages. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222975/python-command-segmentation-fault-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: @Anamitra: Yes, but it didn't work

Comment: @Emil: I tried this, but it didn't solve it either

Answer (score 0):

From https://kb.iu.edu/d/aqsj

> A segmentation fault (aka segfault) is a common condition that causes programs to crash; they are often associated with a file named core . Segfaults are caused by a program trying to read or write an illegal memory location.

I'd suggest that you restart the pi and if that doesn't work - if possible - reinstall the OS. Also this might help: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=267915

EDIT: This is probably caused by a C++ or C error, as stated in the link above. It might also be something related to your modules.

> Unless something is up with Python itself it is most likely that a segfault is occurring in some module you are using, which is likely written in C or C++.

Comment: Restarting didn't work and I am trying my best to save the current OS. Thing is, this occurred out of the blue. I didn't install or update anything. It will be nice to know what happened so that I can avoid it in the future