# segmentation fault, need to prevent this and reduce the run time of my program

Tags: python, algorithm, segmentation-fault, runtime

I solved a problem where I had to find sum of numbers whose digits are made of only 4, 5 and 6.. The numbers have at most x fours, at most y fives and at most z sixes. I successfully passed some of the sample tests. But, I cannot get past other test cases as i keep getting segfault errors. Also, I think my programs run time is seriously long. Any help in reducing the run time, optimizing the solution and -reventing segfault will be appreciated.
Here is my code in Python:

```
from itertools import permutations
x , y, z = raw_input().split(' ')
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
z = int(z)
max = ''
for a in range(z):
    max += '6'
for b in range(y):
    max += '5'
for c in range(x):
    max += '4'
perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(max)]
chances = []
def substring(string):
    possible = []
    for x in range(len(string) + 1):
        for y in range(x, len(string) + 1):
            possible.append(string[x:y])
    return possible
for d in perms:
    chances += list(set(substring(d)))
chances = list(set(chances))
chances.remove('')
sum = 0
for nstr in chances:
    sum += int(nstr)
print sum
```

Comment: This is an algorithm problem. Add it as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what part of the program is consuming the most time.  Looking at the second half, after the call to permutations, I see that you are creating potentially huge lists (in `chances` and `permutations`.  After building them you convert to a set (to eliminate duplicates I suppose) and back again to a list. Why not use a single set instead, like this:

```
chances = set()
def substring(string):
    for x in range(len(string) + 1):
        for y in range(x, len(string) + 1):
            chances.add(string[x:y])
for d in perms:
    substring(d)
chances.remove('')
sum = 0
for nstr in chances:
    sum += int(nstr)
print sum
```

I don't know if that will solve all your problems, but it should help.

Comment: I think that would help, but I am still getting segfault errors.

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035541/what-causes-a-python-segmentation-fault