# python segmentation fault (core dumped) due to recursion limit?

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, recursionerror

I have a small snippet of code that computes the factorial of a number using a nested function shown below:

```
import sys
rec_limit = 10 ** 6
num = 10 ** 5

sys.setrecursionlimit(rec_limit)

def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    ans = n * factorial(n - 1)
    return ans

print(factorial(num))
```

For smaller values of `num`, the program works fine, but for very large values such as the one in the program, a recursion limit is thrown. To avoid this, I used the `sys.setrecursionlimit()` method to increase this limit. However, now I receive a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error on Linux, while on windows, the program just returns without any error.

Please could you explain why this is happening and how I might avoid this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a Python segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035541/what-causes-a-python-segmentation-fault)

Comment: So, what is: `(10 **5)!`? I suspect it is too large to be represented.