# Segmentation fault opening Calc spreadsheet

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, uno, pyuno

I need to crunch a Calc spreadsheet composed of many individual sheets. The Wiki has a detailed [Python guide](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Macros/Python_Guide/Documents#Open) that I am following. I installed the `libreoffice-script-provider-python` package and am able to import the `uno` package without error. However, every time the `create_instance` function is invoked the interpreter crashes with a segmentation fault. A small example is below:

```
import uno

CTX = uno.getComponentContext()
SM = CTX.getServiceManager()

def create_instance(name, with_context=False):
    if with_context:
        instance = SM.createInstanceWithContext(name, CTX)
    else:
        instance = SM.createInstance(name)
    return instance

path = uno.systemPathToFileUrl('/home/user/temp/test.ods')
desktop = create_instance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop', True)
doc = desktop.loadComponentFromURL(path, '_default', 0, ())
```

How can I open a Calc spreadsheet with `uno`?

Setup:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04
- Python: 3.10.12
- LibreOffice: 7.3.7

**Update**: The log of an even smaller example. Launching Calc beforehand does not really change the outcome, but is added for completion.

```
$ soffice --calc --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"
$ python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import uno
>>> CTX = uno.getComponentContext()
>>> SM = CTX.getServiceManager()
>>> name='com.sun.star.frame.Desktop'
>>> instance = SM.createInstanceWithContext(name, CTX)

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I think that your question is not about programming, but of course I may be wrong…

Comment: How are you running the code? Maybe the setup isn't correct, such as LO not listening on a socket, or not running the code as a macro. Rather than us trying to determine your full setup, first go through the tutorial at http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: @JimK Thank you for the link. It contains some nice insight, but it is either too old, or does not apply to Linux. There is no Python executable in my LibreOffice installation. I am running LibreOffice on a socket, pretty much like the MacOS example shows.

Comment: @JimK According to [this answer](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/where-is-los-own-python-interpreter-on-linux/64093/5) LibreOffice does not need to bundle a Python executable on Linux.

Comment: "LibreOffice does not need to bundle a Python executable on Linux" — that's correct. "It is either too old, or does not apply to Linux" — no, it should work with adjustments to the paths for your system. "There is no Python executable" — but your answer says Python 3.10 is installed — is it system-wide or specific to a user (should be the former)? To start with, enter `python3` in a terminal and then `import uno`. What is the problem when trying the tutorial — still the seg fault? If so, on what line?

Comment: @JimK I added an even smaller example. It should answer your questions.

Comment: What is the size of the file?  How many individual sheets are in it? Can you open the file in OpenOffice or Excel? "Segmentation fault" suggests to me a memory error.  Do you have access to the process which created the file?  Assuming yes, can you generate test versions with just one or two sheets? Can you open those from Python? Does it work for some subsets of sheets but not others? If you create a small test spreadsheet in OpenOffice format (via Excel or Calc or whatever), can your code open that in Python?  Try to separate "problem with the spreadsheet" from "problem with Python".

Comment: The answers to this question have some suggestions for dealing with Python segmentation faults in general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035541/what-causes-a-python-segmentation-fault

Comment: @SarahMesser The problem I report is independent of the type of spreadsheet. It happens with a new file without contents or other files with multiple sheets. As you can see from the update, I can replicate the segmentation fault even without opening a file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I used your setup (Ubuntu 22.04, Python 3.10, LO 7.3.7), and indeed, the code listed in the question does produce a segmentation fault.

But it looks like you didn't even try the [tutorial](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html) even though your comments suggest otherwise.  The resolver is required to connect to the running instance of LibreOffice, as shown in "First play with the Python shell to get familiar."

```
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
    "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext)
ctx = resolver.resolve(
    "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext")
```

In contrast, the code linked in the question wasn't intended to be used with that setup. It works when run from within LibreOffice as a macro, where `XSCRIPTCONTEXT` is available.

Comment: Can you update this answer with a link to that tutorial you refer?