# Ubuntu 11.10/12.04 segfault when accessing webcam via pygame.camera

Tags: python, pygame, ubuntu-11.10, ubuntu-12.04

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04, ran all the updates, then ran `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libsdl1.2-dev python-pygame`. However, when I run the following in the python interpreter:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
cam.get_image()
```

I get:

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any suggestions?

Update: this occurs with a fresh install of 11.10 as well.

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663841/python-tracing-a-segmentation-fault might help you at least pin down which line is causing the problem.

Comment: Oh, the segfault definitely occurs at the final line (I entered the lines one by one).

Answer (score 4):

Well, the solution was head-smackingly simple: I forgot to call `cam.start()` before `cam.get_image()`.