# How to Disconnect a python DBus connection?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dbus, qdbus

I made some kind of answering machine for pidgin client that uses Linuxes DBus to make connection with pidgin. the code is this:

```
class DBus_Answer():
    def __init__(self, text = "No text"):  
        self.answer = text
        bus_loop = DBusQtMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
        self.bus = dbus.SessionBus()
        self.bus.add_signal_receiver(self.pidgin_control_func,
                                     dbus_interface="im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface",
                                     signal_name="ReceivedImMsg")

    def pidgin_control_func(self, account, sender, message, conversation, flags):
        obj = self.bus.get_object("im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService", "/im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject")
        purple = dbus.Interface(obj, "im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface")
        purple.PurpleConvImSend(purple.PurpleConvIm(conversation), self.answer)
```

now I want to use it as a module in another program. I called it like this:

```
answering_machine.DBus_Answer(message)
```

the problem is, when I stop the second program (the program that has this one as a module) and then start it again, I'll get a `segmentation fault` because it want to make another connection to the DBus and it seams it's not regular!

Other wise I want to give the chance of disabling this module to user. I tried to use an `if` statement. It will work for the first time. but if user run the module for once, he can't disable it any more.

Comment: It is hard to tell if you do not post a self-contained example. Can you post a small program using `DBus_Answer` which exhibits the problem? Getting the main loop for each answer seems wrong, you should have only one main loop. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

segmentation faults occur because in a python module (written in C) a pointer is NULL, or because it points to random memory (probably never initialized to anything), or because it points to memory that has been freed/deallocated/"deleted".so your problem is probably with your memory.try trace the segfault using methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663841/python-tracing-a-segmentation-fault/2664232#2664232)