# Jupyter Lab shutting down and system being logged of on running python code

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, crash, jupyter-lab, healpy

I am using Jupyter Lab with python for data analysis of cosmological data sets.
I use Dell Vostro 5515 laptop with 16gb ram and Ryzen7 processor. My OS is Fedora 36 with KDE and Xfce environments.

The problem is that on running my .ipynb notebook for some time, it closes down abruptly if I am in KDE. If I m in xfce, it also closes all the applications and logs out my session.

The crash happens mostly while running a function called `compute_full_master` in `pymaster` library in python. But has also happened rarely while running some other functions.

I have tried to get error messages by running jupyter lab in `--debug` mode, but when the crash happens, the terminal is also closed. I do not know how to get the crash details in other ways.

I have tried to run the code in firefox, chrome, and VSCode.

I am sorry if I have not provided any details necessary and I am happy to provide any if anyone can help!

EDIT:

A simple example:

```
arr_len = 8394753
x = np.arange(arr_len)
plt.figure(figsize=(25,15))
plt.plot(x, y_1 - y_2)
plt.plot(x, y_1 - y_3)
plt,plot(x, y_1 - y_4)
plt.ylim((-1e-6,1e-6))
```

The arrays y_1, y_2, y_3 and y_4 have the length arr_len and are complex. The imaginary part does not matter. The notebook is already having run some code in previous cells. But running this plotting cell a few times caused the shut down many times.

Comment: you should provide a minimal executable example, also I recommend to post this as an issue to pymaster instead of stack overflow: https://github.com/LSSTDESC/NaMaster/issues

Comment: The crash also happened while running some other memory-intensive functions. Pymaster was just the most common example. Also, I could not reproduce the issue in other computers. What I am looking for is a way to debug what is the issue.Basically, how to get the error messages as the terminal also keeps closing down?

Comment: can you reproduce outside of Jlab? you could run under `gdb` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663841/python-tracing-a-segmentation-fault, maybe the kernel?

Comment: you need to provide an executable example for people to be able to help you.